How to make NumPy array initialization faster?
My work requires constructing large square matrices of order 1000 as numpy arrays, whose elements are defined analytically as a function of their indices. Right now I create a zero array, and loop over the elements to construct my required array. This by itself takes a hefty time to evaluate. Is there any way to make the construction more efficient or faster, say by using GPU or parallel computing or the like?
Example: I want to construct a (1000, 1000) matrix J (which is the Jacobian of the system I'm studying). I have the definition for Jij given by a function J_ij(i, j, a, b), where a and b are parameters which are fixed for a given matrix. I begin by creating the array J of zeros, and iterate along the entries and update them according to the function J_ij. The full codebase is given here, but following is the only relevant part:
    def J_ij(self, i: int, j: int, xi_mat: np.ndarray, eta: np.ndarray):
        """
        Calculates the ij-th element of the jacobian* for input pattern eta

        Parameters
        ----------
        i,j : int
            Indices of the matrix
        xi_mat : np.ndarray
            Memory pattern matrix of shape (p, n)
        eta : np.ndarray
            Input pattern of shape (n, )

        Returns
        -------
        float value of ij-th element of J
        """
        n = self.n
        p = self.p
        jij = 0
        for mu in range(p):
            jij += xi_mat[mu, i]*xi_mat[mu, j]*eta[i]*eta[j]
        if i == j:
            for k in range(n):
                for mu in range(p):
                    jij -= xi_mat[mu, i]*xi_mat[mu, k]*eta[i]*eta[k]
        return jij/n

    def jacobian(self, eta: np.ndarray):
        """
        Generates the jacobian* for stability analysis

        Parameters
        ----------
        eta : np.ndarray
            Input pattern

        Returns
        -------
        jacobian matrix as a (n, n) numpy array
        """
        n = self.n
        J = np.zeros((n, n))
        if self.xi_mat is None:
            self.init_patterns()
        xi_mat = self.xi_mat
        for _ in range(n**2):
            i = _ // n
            j = _  % n
            J[i, j] += self.J_ij(i, j, xi_mat, eta)
        return J

xi_mat is a matrix of rows of binary patterns made of 1 and -1. eta is one such binary pattern.
I tried using cupy instead of numpy, but due to (independent) issues related to my dedicated GPU being not recognized by CUDA in my Arch linux installation, it actually took longer time than numpy.

Look into numba. If you don't show what you're actually doing then it's not possible to give targeted advice

Vectorize the loop. But there is no general recipies (well, numba could be one. Or coding in C rather than python. But in pure python/numpy there isn't). It depends on what you do. You are asking "how can I optimize the code" without showing any code... The only thing we know is 1. That you use a for loop. You shouldn't. Optimize numpy code try to avoid for loop. And half of questions/answers in numpy are about how to remove a for loop. But people show their code, obviously.


That you initialize a zero array, and then loop over it to overwrite those 0. Then, no need to initialize a zero array. You should use np.empty rather than np.zeros. But since initialization of 0 probably cost 1000 times less than your secret for loop, for now you wouldn't see the difference. It is only when you will have optimized your secret code that this may gain yet a bit more time.


Again, if you want help on how to optimize your code, you need to show your code. What is f?

The part you've show is just a convoluted way to do a 2d for loop. That is equivalent of for i in range(1000): for j in range(1000): J[i,j] = f(i,j,a,b). Which would be equivalent to J = f(np.arange(1000)[:,None], np.arange(1000)[None,:], a, b) if f was vectorized. Which is the whole point of the question: how to vectorize f. We can't answer that without f.

https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html, maybe if you would implement system into JAX it would make everything for you, if you have hardware supporting this package

@quester that is just yet another way to generally speaking reply to the very generic question "how to make my code faster" when no code is shown. Basically the answer being "use a faster language/interpreter/platform". Sure, they could use jax, numba, ctypes, python c-api, or switch to rust, etc, etc. But there is also a good chance that the numpy question could be answered with numpy,... if we had the question. f is probably already vectorized, or almost so.

Your jacobian function looks a lot like a straightforward matrix multiply, and can be vectorized simply to the following (assuming that xi_mat is a p-by-n matrix and eta is an n-element vector):
M = xi_mat * eta
J = M.T @ M
J -= np.diag(np.sum(J, axis=0))
J /= n

As this uses a NumPy matrix multiply, it should run substantially faster than the manual loop. Timing results on my iPhone for n=1000, p=10, and random xi_mat and eta:

original jacobian calculation: 10.37 seconds
new calculation: 0.00609 seconds (1700x faster)


Note that, amusingly, my iPhone is faster than the Linux server I have on hand (possibly because the phone’s numpy is SIMD accelerated), but a similar 1000x speed up is observed on that server too.
